# Is it possible to redistribute .NET Framework 3.5 32-bit only?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, 32-bit

The offline installer for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is 200 MB large. We're wondering whether it's possible (both technically and legally) to split it up by target architecture - so as to produce a separate installer for the 32-bit version. The idea is that it might be significantly smaller.

I am aware of the bootstrapper, which will only download the necessary bits. Just wondering about other possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick summary of your options, built by Scott Hanselman:

http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/

So the answer is, yes, you can get a full install for under 200MB.  But, the best way is to give the users the online installer, so that it can choose the best framework version for them.  This will minimize downloading.